# subset of data using regular exp in spark

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

I have sample data like below

```
     class: 9
        section: A
             stud : Robert
                 subject: maths
                 mark  : 69
                 subject:science
                 mark: 75
        stud : Billy
                subject: maths
                mark  : 69
                subject:science
                mark: 75
         stud : Venice
                subject: maths
                mark  : 69
               subject:science
               mark: 75
        stud : Marc
               subject: maths
               mark  : 69
               subject:science
               mark: 75
    class: 10
        section: A
           stud : Agnes
                subject: maths
                mark  : 69
                subject:science
                mark: 75
           stud : Sarah
                subject: maths
                mark  : 69
                subject:science
                mark: 75
          stud : Scott
               subject: maths
              mark  : 69
              subject:science
              mark: 75
        stud : Alex
             subject: maths
             mark  : 69
             subject:science
             mark: 75
line1
line2
line3
...
line n
```

I am trying to extract class 9 student data out of this file. Here is my code

```
   val datafile = sc.textFile("file.txt").collect().mkString(" ")
    // to take the data I needed from whole file
    val datpattern = """(class: 9).*?(?=\bline\s) 
    val finaldata = datpattern.findAllIn(datafile)
    //student data extract regex
    val stupattern = "section: (\S+)\s+ stud : ([\w\S]+)\s+ subject: ([\w\S]+)\s+ mark : (\d+)"""".r


val finalresult = finaldata.flatMap { a => stupattern findAllIn a }
                           .map {l = 
                        val stupattern(section,stuname,sub,mark) = l
                        (section,stuname,sub,mark)
}
.foreach(println)
```

But this gave me only first record in each class that too only the first subject & mark. (Robert maths mark & Agnes Maths mark from class 9 & 10th S A section.

I thought this is because only that matches entire pattern.

I tried to change it like with 0 or more occurences for subject & mark. something like below (Only the lines I have changed given below)

```
val stupattern = "section: (\S+)\s+ stud : ([\w\S]+)\s+ (subject: ([\w\S]+)\s+ mark : (\d+))*"""".r


    val finalresult = finaldata.flatMap { a => stupattern findAllIn a }
                               .map {l = 
                            val stupattern(section,stuname,{sub,mark}) = l//This doesn't even let me compile
                            (section,stuname,sub,mark)//This doesn't even let me compiled
    }
    .foreach(println)
```

It error out like for those 2 lines "Illegal start of pattern".

Can someone tell me how to extract repeat subset of data from above?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To only grab class 9, use `"""(?m)^\s*class: 9\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*class: \d).*)*"""` pattern.

Comment: Thank you for response Wiktor.  that gives me class 9&10 first record  . that is robert maths mark alone. ho we can get all of his mark list along with students? and match them with ? and also , is there any way to iterate on subset and assign values? Like Iwant (9, A, robert, math, 69)\n(9,A, robert,science,75).. goes on till (10,A, alex, sceince,75).. is there a technique we can achieve this?

Comment: Don't do it with regex, just read the file line by line and check what data the line contains and collect the information you need. With regex, it will not look "tidy".

Comment: so regex is not the right approach. Thanks wiktor for your time.